# zip event logs using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm kind of new to powershell and I need some help with writing this script for my work.

I have months of event logs stored in a drive and I want to compress all those event logs using powershell to do so but I absolutely have no idea how to start as the file names have timestamp.

For a start I would like to have 1 script to zip up all the logs according to the month that they were exported. Then another script for future logs dated one month earlier to be compressed. I plan to have this second script to run on a monthly schedule.

Sincerely appreciate the help in advance!

I thought out the flow on how the script would probably go.

clean up event log script

```
Define Drive = F drive

function findeventlog
Get current month = eg. May
Find all files earlier than [get current month] 
Get current year
define exclusion list of zip files = "*.zip"
filter "[get current year]-[get current month]-*"

define event log folder = Drive\eventlogbackup\eventlogs 
define zip destination folder = F:\eventlogbackup\eventlog -filter -recurse

define zips to create = find items in event log folder and exclude (list)
define zips to create.count
zip (define zips to create)
```

process flow for compress event log script

```
Define Drive = F drive

function findeventlog
Get current month = eg. May
Find all files 1 month earlier than [get current month] 
Get current year
define exclusion list of zip files = "*.zip"

define event log folder = Drive\eventlogbackup\eventlogs -filter -recurse
define zip destination folder = F:\eventlogbackup\eventlog

define zips to create = find items in event log folder and exclude (list)
define zips to create.count
zip (define zips to create)
```

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping colleagues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and ***serious*** coding attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code (not pseudo code) in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Kudos for pseudocode approach. Since the script is going to need more work than usual, let me try CW answer. Try and work forward from the script and feel free to ask help for specific questions.

```
function findeventlog {
    # Get current month = eg. May
    # Find all files earlier than [get current month]

    # List all files that have last write time in the past.
    # Get-Date returns a DateTime that contains methods for addition
    $files = Get-Childitem -path c:\path\to\logs | ` # ` is used here for wrapping
      Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le (get-date).AddMonths(-1) } 

    # define exclusion list of zip files = "*.zip"
    # Files collection can be filtered. ? is shorthand for where-object
    # For a list of all properties, refer to learn.microsoft.com or use Get-Member
    $files = $files | ? { $_.someProperty -ne something }

    # define event log folder = Drive\eventlogbackup\eventlogs 
    # define zip destination folder = F:\eventlogbackup\eventlog -filter -recurse

    # define zips to create = find items in event log folder and exclude (list)
    # define zips to create.count
    # zip (define zips to create)
    Compress-Archive -LiteralPath $files -Destination c:\my\archive\location
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can u help with my below questions? My questions: 1. If my event logs are dated from Jan - April, how do I make my script into a function so that I do not need to specify the months? 2. When I don't specify the months, can I do my zipping in such a way that it's filtered to the month? like 05-04-2019.evtx should be zipped into ArchiveApr2019.zip

Any other suggestions to fine tune my script is welcomed! I'll learn and improve along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This really helps. I have come up with something but definitely needs further fine tuning. Here's what I have. I'm using an answer because this is too long for a comment.

```
$drive = "F:"
$exclude = @("whatever.evtx")
$eventlogfolder = "$drive\destinationpath"
$filesApr = Get-ChildItem -path $eventlogfolder -exclude $exclude | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -le (Get-date).AddMonths(-1)}

compress-archive $filesApr -Destinationpath $eventlogfolder\ArchiveApr2019.zip -force -confirm:false
```

My questions:
1. If my event logs are dated from Jan - April, how do I make my script into a function so that I do not need to specify the months?
2. When I don't specify the months, can I do my zipping in such a way that it's filtered to the month? like 05-04-2019.evtx should be zipped into ArchiveApr2019.zip

Any other suggestions to fine tune my script is welcomed! I'll learn and improve along the way.